Strapi Filter with $containsi(not case-sensitive) parameter, doesn’t work with cyrillic
i have name field in cyrillic and trying to search by that field using $containsi parameter
fetch("https://example.com/api/products?filters%5B$or%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D%5B$containsi%5D=%D0%B3%D1%80", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});

i tried to use fuzzy-search plugin and it works but i want just a regular search not fuzzy
that will show items that contains the search query
(with fuzzy search it shows if the item contains some letters from the search query)

Hello, I would suggest that you open a GitHub issue about that.
Or check if there is not one that already exists.
I can confirm that it doesn't work.

I found that the issue is in the database when i changed the locale in database it started to work i use postgres and i needed ukrainian locale so the command looks like this:
update pg_database set datcollate='uk_UA.UTF-8', datctype='uk_UA.UTF-8' where datname='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';

you can see all available locales with this command:
locale -a

by default docker postgres image have only en locale so i make apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales locales-all to install all locales
this is my docker compose:
postgres:
    image: postgres:15.1
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales locales-all && docker-entrypoint.sh -c 'shared_buffers=256MB' -c 'max_connections=200'"
    networks:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - docker.env

docker.env:
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=db_name
LANG=uk_UA.UTF-8

